# Angular 4 - fetching products and categories

Tags: angular

I am working on a angular website in which there is a product page and on this page there are some categories and within every categories there are products, I am able to fetch categories and products but I dont know how to combine them.

like, I request for categories and then for each category I again request the API for the products in that category.

I may sound novice (which I am actually) but any help is appreciated.

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ProductsService } from '../services/products.service';

import { Products } from '../models/Products';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-products',
  templateUrl: './products.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./products.component.css']
})
export class ProductsComponent implements OnInit {
  productList: Products[];
  productArray:any;

  constructor(private http:HttpClient, private products:ProductsService) {

   }

  ngOnInit():void {
    this.products.getProducts().subscribe(products=>{
      this.productList = products;
      this.productArray = this.productList['results'];
      console.log(this.productList['results']);
    });

   }

}

My product service 

    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
    import { Products } from '../models/Products';


@Injectable()
export class ProductsService {
  productURL: string = 'http://itgenesys.com/mdevices/webservices/api.php?rquest=getproducts&catid=8';

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  getProducts(): Observable<Products[]>{
   return this.http.get<Products[]>(this.productURL)
  }

}
```

Here is the image of the page
[1.Category list, 2. products in that category 3. Accordion for showing products.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uPTdM.png)

Product array

```
{
"status": "1",
"msg": "product list",
"results": [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "title": "MAXLITE  MACINTOSH FIBER OPTIC BLADES",
        "description": "With over 25 Years of experience and a specialized manufacturing setup, Medical Devices laryngoscopes are proven to be exceptionally reliable and durable. These are made from Superior quality materials and are subjected to strict quality control measures. Our Laryngoscope systems are not only designed to be more efficient, but also to be the most economical.\r\n\r\nMaxlite Laryngoscopes are built with an integrated Fiber Optic bundle with no cavities to trap dirt or body fluids, thus allowing the blade to be easily cleaned and decontaminated. This contributes largely to the elimination of cross infection.",
        "parentcatname": null,
        "parentcatid": "8",
        "subcatname": null,
        "subcatid": "1",
        "date": "2018-03-29 05:36:55",
        "mainphoto": "Tulips.jpg"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "title": "Iphone 6",
        "description": "With over 25 Years of experience and a specialized manufacturing setup, Medical Devices laryngoscopes are proven to be exceptionally reliable and durable. These are made from Superior quality materials and are subjected to strict quality control measures. Our Laryngoscope systems are not only designed to be more efficient, but also to be the most economical",
        "parentcatname": null,
        "parentcatid": "4",
        "subcatname": null,
        "subcatid": "8",
        "date": "2018-03-29 06:50:19",
        "mainphoto": "Hydrangeas.jpg"
    }
]
```

}

Comment: `but I dont know how to combine them` What exactly are you trying to achieve? What's the desired result?

Comment: On the product page there are category listing and within those categories products will come, so one loop I want to run for categories and another for products for each category.

Categoies are selected by users but they are fixed so I want to fetch categories and products both with ngOnInit when the page loads.

Comment: What's the value of `this.productList` after you receive the data from the service?

Comment: I have added the JSON, Please check. it has the category Id

Comment: can anyone help me please?